# How to remove last files opened per application in Ccleaner

Tags: ccleaner

When a program is open, right click on it in taskbar opens a list of last files opened in this program. Ccleaner used to clear that list by default before, not any more it seems. Any idea how to achieve this currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CCleaner used to clear that list by default before, not any more it seems.

These items (last files opened) are removed if you enable the checkbox for Windows Explorer > Taskbar Jump Lists on the Windows tab:

[image]

Note:

- Tested with Notepad++ (which was closed when I ran CCcleaner).