# Where are Windows jump-list tasks stored?

Tags: windows-7, opera, jumplist

I have a problem from time to time with Opera's jump-list tasks.

It seems that, after some upgrades, they stop working because they point to the old version number (2 releases back):

[image: jump-list]

Here is what happens when I click on it:

[image: result]

(That file path does not exist.)

I guess something is wrong with Opera's updates, so I am thinking of fixing it manually every time (I have reported this to them but not sure if someone cares or notices posts in the place I've posted it). Does anyone know where this data (for the jump-list task) is stored?

Or maybe the data is correct and they are simply cached somewhere and I need to clear that cache?

Comment: Why don't you just clear the jumplist?  CCleaner can solve this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried running CCleaner. It didn't help. I also don't see any specific setting for jump-lists on it. I don't know if it's named after something more general. But I have most of the clearing options active on  it.

Comment: @NoOne They are called "Taskbar Jump Lists". See my answer [How to remove last files opened per application in Ccleaner](http://superuser.com/a/1046311)

Comment: @Ramhound Oh! Indeed! CCleaner has a setting for this under `Windows Explorer`. And it re-creates the files inside `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations`. Just it doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately. I guess the problem is in another place from where it takes data to re-create those files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows keeps the jump list cache here:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
```

Note that `Recent` doesn't appear to be a child of `Windows`, but it's there; just copy/paste that path into the Run box. You'll be taken to a place that has lots of `.customDestinations-ms` files.

#### Old versions of Opera (pre-30?)

Use one of Opera's jump list items and see which file gets updated. (For me, it was titled `7fc0edee3248ce7`.) Delete that file. That will break the jump list. Run Opera normally by just clicking the pinned icon; the file will be recreated and the jump list will be restored.

Also, Opera keeps some proprietary data here:

```
%APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Jump List Icons
```

If you rename or remove that folder, Opera will recreate it. It appears that there's one file for every Speed Dial item.

#### New versions

Apparently, Opera no longer attempts to restore the jump list items. I had to completely uninstall (i.e. torch user data as well) and reinstall it to get the items back.

Comment: Indeed, the jump-list tasks are stored there! Thanks. :) However, I see that they don't get updated every time I use a jump-list taks (perhaps because my jump-list tasks are broken to begin with). I have located the desired one by looking inside the files. After deleting it, I couldn't have it recreated. I've opened Opera but there were no taks any more. I have tried editing this file with a HEX editor, but there are MANY identical paths in there...

Comment: @NoOne Right, deleting the file will clear the jump list. Launch Opera again by clicking the pinned taskbar icon. The file will re-appear and the list will be restored.

Comment: I have closed Opera and reopened it from the taskbar's pinned icon and form the start menu. It won't re-create the file. Not sure why... Does it recreate it on your machine? That's weird...

Comment: @NoOne Hmm, I just updated to the latest version of Opera and it no longer works for me. Does rebooting help?

Comment: @NoOne Well, I tried lots of things, and the only thing that did it was a full uninstall and reinstall of Opera. :/

Comment: It seems thatt using CCleaner re-creates those files: http://superuser.com/a/1046311. But it doesn't solve the problem. I guess the problem is in another place from where it takes data to re-create those files.